# How to handle Dimensions with multiple keys in Crossfilter.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have data which is similar to the json below.

```
data = [
    {"student_id":  1, "clubs": ["Photography", "Drama"  ],   "sports": ["Soccer", "Baseball", "Biking"],     "gender": "Male",   "age" : 12},
    {"student_id":  2, "clubs": ["Debating", "Drama", "Art"  ],   "sports": [ "Basketball", ],     "gender": "Male",   "age" : 15},
    {"student_id":  3, "clubs": ["Math Club",  "Drama"  ],   "sports": ["Swimming", "Running", "Biking"],     "gender": "Male",   "age" : 12},
    {"student_id":  4, "clubs": [ "Drama", "Art"  ],   "sports": [ "Baseball", ],     "gender": "Male",   "age" : 11},
    {"student_id":  5, "clubs": ["Math Club", "Photography"  ],   "sports": ["Basketball", "Biking"],     "gender": "Female",   "age" : 12},
    {"student_id":  6, "clubs": ["Drama", "Art"  ],   "sports": [ "Volleyball", ],     "gender": "Female",   "age" : 16},

]
```

Can I use crossfilter.js to answer questions ( essentially group count or sum ) such as how many students are members of the Photography Club and play Basketball.

Essentially use a have chart for Clubs and another one for Sports.
Display the counts for each of the attributes ( dimensions ) and filter across them. 
Yes the students may get double counted because they could be members of many clubs or playing many sports.

Comment: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try Dimensions with Arrays